# How do I stop Flume from removing the date and hostname from syslog events it's receiving?

Tags: apache-kafka, flume, syslog

This is a sample log entry I'm sending to flume from a linux rsyslog:

```
Nov 30 09:16:12 server1 achaos: Sep 1 07:45:53 cent65-template testLog[13942]: [DEBUG] [UUID= MAX= MIN=] ENTERED findByMin for 999
```

This is what flume sends to Kafka, or writes to disk:

```
achaos: Sep 1 07:45:53 cent65-template testLog[13942]: [DEBUG] [UUID= MAX= MIN=] ENTERED findByMin for 999
```

As you can see, the date and hostname at the beginning of the event are gone. This happens regardless of the syslog source.

This is my flume config. Pretty straightforward:

```
a1.sources  = source1
a1.channels = channel1
a1.sinks = sink1

a1.sources.source1.type = syslogudp
a1.sources.source1.port = 514
a1.sources.source1.host = 10.10.2.18
a1.sources.source1.channels = channel1

a1.sinks.sink1.type = org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
a1.sinks.sink1.topic = firewall
a1.sinks.sink1.brokerList = 10.10.2.1:6667,10.10.2.2:6667
a1.sinks.sink1.channel = channel1

a1.channels.channel1.type = memory
a1.channels.channel1.capacity = 10000000
a1.channels.channel1.transactionCapacity = 1000
```

From extensive googling, it seems the issue has to do with flume headers. I don't understand how this behavior can possibly be helpful to me. I have not found any sample config that appears to do what I want.

What changes do I need to make to knock some sense into Flume's thick head?

FYI: The data is going from Flume1 -> Kafka -> Flume2 -> HDFS

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Host Interceptor](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#host-interceptor) to add hostname to the Flume events and then you use the extra header either by doing some [Morphline](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#morphline-interceptor) magic (to re-add the host string to each line) or path substitution when writing to [HDFS](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#hdfs-sink%20HDFS). (`%{headername}` strings will be interpolated in HDFS paths)

Comment: Thanks for your answer bessbd. Do you know why the Date and Hostname disappear to begin with? Because I still don't understand flume's default behavior and I'd like to know.

Comment: Sorry @gozu , I'm afraid no. At least, not from the top of my mind. I suggest you look at https://github.com/apache/flume/blob/trunk/flume-ng-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/source/SyslogUDPSource.java if you want to understand syslogudp source better.

Comment: Also, i find nothing regarding morphline that doesn't involve solr sinks online. Nothing about kafka sinks. am I missing something?

Comment: Basically, you can have any Java code run on your events you want. You do the code, you configure it and Flume will make it happen. -
https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#morphline-interceptor